# Main menu is disabled in iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app

Steps to reproduce:

In Slide Over/Split View mode open any question and tap on "Add comment" button:

> [image: step1]

Don't type anything, just tap back button:

> [image: step2]

Tap on the main menu button:

> [image: step3]

Main menu items are disabled:

> [image: step4]

I.e. impossible to change site, watch rep or inbox, etc.

To make it active again you need to discard comment after first step.

- App Version: 1.6.5.3
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: @user00001 what's your device/OS/app version?

Comment: iPhone 6/Apple/1.6.4

Comment: @user00001 as far as I know [Slide Over/Split Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207582) can't be used with iPhone. This is iPad only feature.